# Are there already Neural Network AIs that can play object-finding games?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, computer-games

Neural networks are good at image analysis. They are also being used in video games which could outperform professional human players. I wonder if they can also play a purely object-finding game where a player needs to find objects in a photo as shown in the picture.[image]

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case in ML, the only way to find out is to try it (or find someone else who has already tried it).  You might be interested in methods for object detection, which basically do what you are asking for.  The dataset they are trained on has a critical impact on their performance; they need to be trained on a large set of images that is "similar" to the ones they will be used on.